# Handling SIGCHLD, how to record the return values of children as they die

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals, low-level

```
void childSignalHandler(int signo) {
    int status;

    pid_t pid = wait(&status);

    struct PIDList* record = getRecordForPID(childlist, pid);
    if (record != NULL)
        record->returnValue = status;
}
```

Quick question:

I want this handler to, when a child dies (this app spawns lots of children), get their return value and record it (last three lines). Will this do it, or am I getting all this API business wrong?

Thank you for your time!

(also, linux API terminology is creepy as hell, check for dying children and whatnot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job, if you set your function as a handler for `SIGCHLD`.

However, `SIGCHLD` can be send to parent process *not only* after the child exited. Some other events are signaled this way as well (for instance when the child is stopped). See [man wait(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Note signals are not queued.  If two children die in quick succession, you may only recieve one `SIGCHLD`.  So, you should actually loop around calling `waitpid()` until there are no more exiting processes to handle:

```
int status;
pid_t pid;

while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        struct PIDList *record = getRecordForPID(childlist, pid);

        if (record != NULL)
            record->returnValue = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that on modern systems, `SIGCHLD` is queued, but the code in the question is still wrong as there is no guarantee that `wait()` will return the pid the current instance of `SIGCHLD` is for. When `wait()` or a similar function reports status of a child process, the corresponding `SIGCHLD` signal, if any, is considered accepted and the signal handler will not be called.

Comment: @jilles I also have observed this behavior: `"the corresponding SIGCHLD signal, if any, is considered accepted and the signal handler will not be called"`(happy debugging time...). Because I was not sure if my application behaves properly, I am happy to have found your comment on this now. I'm still looking for an official reference.

Comment: @jilles This is it, isn't it? `If _POSIX_REALTIME_SIGNALS is defined, and the implementation queues the SIGCHLD signal, then if wait() or waitpid() returns because the status of a child process is available, any pending SIGCHLD signal associated with the process ID of the child process shall be discarded` from http://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid

Comment: @Jan-Philip Gehrcke Yes, that's it. I would suggest a more official site such as `www.unix.org` instead of `die.net` though.